# Is there any way to fetch all users into a list in rules?

Tags: rules, views

I want to know if there is any way to fetch all users into a list in [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)?

I used [Views Bulk Operations (VBO)](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) and "Load items from VBO" in Rules. But it seems it doesn't work !!

Comment: i could do this because i have relations module enebeled, all my "top" users have a relationship with admin user, so i did a loop with "site:current-user:relation-subuser-user";  react on: user adimn is viewed. no VBO needed in this case.

Comment: I check vbo with content. Actually I thought maybe I have a mistake with users. so I decided to test vbo - rules via content. so I made a view to load all nodes and then tried to fetch result of this view via rules and vbo loader and I saw this way is not working too ! I don't know if I have any mistake in my settings or maybe vbo module has some issue.
I downloaded a movie from vimeo but I have done all same as this movie !!!
I AM CONFUSED A LOT

Comment: VBO works on rules components, not in rules. another point: you are talking to fecth users, not content, try vbo view on users, not content, apply filters as needed. see this video: https://drupalize.me/videos/using-rules-components-vbo?p=1157

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming your question is about D7. A possible answer to your question is to use the [Views Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_rules) module, as further detailed below.

#### 1. About the Views Rules module

The [Views Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_rules) module makes [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) data available in [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), enabling intuitive rule configuration for dynamic data. Some details from its project page:

> ... provides two types of elements in [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), configured with a "Rules" view display:
>
> - **Views loop**: A views loop is similar to a regular Rules loop, but allows looping over rows of view results.
>
>   [image]
> - **Collect view result rows (action)**: This action collects each variable in all view result rows into list variables for use in Rules.
>
> ***Tip***: When selecting the data type for variables in the view, if the field is an entity identifier (e.g. Node ID), you can set the data type to the entity type (i.e. Node) to directly use the variable in Rules as an entity!

#### 2. Create a view of display type 'Rules'

After you enable the [Views Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_rules) module, you can use [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) to create a view of those users you want "*to fetch into a list in rules*" (as in your question). Add of view of display type ***`Rules`*** (important, that's the key to make it work!). Here is how you can add such display:

[image]

Next configure the row variables, by using the link that says "edit field info", as shown here:

[image]

You probably want to use one or more of the variables similar to those that are shown in this screenprint:

[image]

#### 3. Create a rule using the view of display type 'Rules'

Create the appropriate Rules Actions in your rule, using these guidelines:

- Use the link that says `Add view loop` to add a Views loop, and select the "Rules" display created in the previous step.
- Configure the parameters and variable names.
- For each user contained in your Views loop, perform whatever Rules Action that fits your requirement, using the variables you configured at the end of the previous step (you may have to revisit the previous step to add more similar variables there if needed). If you created the *Rules row variables* as suggested in the previous step, your actual eMail can use tokens such as `[usermail:value]`, `[username:value]`, etc.

***Easy, no?***

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *process the results of a [VBO](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) enabled view via [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)*, then typically your rule should include these Rules Actions (in the order specified):

- Load the VBO list of users that you want to be processed.
- Add a loop to perform a Rules Action, for each user contained in your Views results.

For more details, have a look at the tutorial "[How to process the results of a VBO enabled view via Rules?](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/90)".